# How to structure sub node of collections in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to migrate the following structure from real time database to Firestore :

```
•   Resources
    o   SENT
           resId1
               •    name : xxxx
               •    url : xxx
           resI2
               •    name ……
   o    ACCEPT
           resId3
           etc……
   o    REFUSED
           restIdn 
           etc….
```

So under root Node" Resources" I have some sub nodes (SENT, ACCEPT, REFUSED, ...) that contain List of resources items.

With Firestore it seems I can't have subCollection directly under collection (When I try to reproduce this structure with Firestore in the admin console I need to create an intermediate document  like:

```
Collection --> document --> SubCollection --> documents
```

Witch lead to that structure:

```
Resources --> SENT --> SENT --> resId1 {name: xxx, url: yyyy}
```

So the sub node "SENT" is duplicated twice (one for the document and one for the sub collection).
This is not an improvement or a simplification at all, if I compare with firebase real time database.
Do I miss something? What is the best way for such kind of database structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edited 10/13/2017 @ 11am)

It seems that there are two structures that will work for you.

**Option 1: Three Root Collections**

Create three collections at the root of your Firestore database

- `resources-sent`
- `resources-accept`
- `resources-refused`

Each one contains documents.

**Option 2: One Root Collection**

Firestore allows for compound queries, so you could just make one collection at the root called `resources` and add a `type` parameter to each document where `type` is one of `[sent, accept, refused]`.

Then you can do queries like this:

```
// Get all sent resources
db.collection("resources").where("type", "==", "sent").get()
```

Because of Firestore's built in indexes this query will always be fast!'

**Option 3: Subcollections.**

Create a root collection called `resources` containing only three docs:

- `sent`
- `accept`
- `refused`

For each of these docs create a `resources` subcollection.

So to get all sent resources:

```
// Get all sent resources
db.collection("resources").doc("sent").collection("resources").get()
```

Comment: No Resources is not the root database, it just a  collection (or a Node) of particular items. And I may have more than 3 sub categories

Comment: Do resources belong to some other document?  I need more information.

Comment: No Resources is a first node after root (like a kind of TABLE); there are some other root nodes, the only diferrence is that this node "Resources" is divided in subcategories (for the example Sent, Accept, etc.....)

Comment: Option 2 it's good to no know that query will always be fast and it can suit many use case. But for some specific use cases (and to make it easier to maintain in the admin console); I'sd like to have a "root" category in the tree node, Option 1 doesn't suit because the number of sub-categories may be more than 3 and it would appear clearer to present them under a "root category" like "Resources". If it was easy with RTDB it seems not possible with Firestore.Maybe a new improvement could be to allow putting a SubCollection directly under a collection (not sure it's technically possible).

Comment: @toofoo I have added a third option if you really want to do it that way

Comment: It makes sense .Instead of duplicate the subcollection name as it is in my question, you split the "Resources"  name; it looks little bit cleaner. Thanks for your answers.